# Android "SDK Manager" does not install

Tags: android, sdk, installation

I have already downloaded the content of the link: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

It seems to me that it contains every thing i want. In the first step when i run the
 **SDK Manager** i face with the page:[image]

And it means that everything is installed, but it still trying to fetch some files like `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml`

And finally i face with this:
[image]

And it remains in this situation.now my questions are:

1-Why i can not see the SDK manager in my `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features`
as an installed program?

2-If **SDK manager** is not installed how can i do that?

3-According to what i have downloaded can i install everything locally without connecting to internet?

Comment: 1) You won't see SDK manager in your `Control Panel` because it isn't a Windows service. It is a Java program that doesn't do anything Windows specific.

Comment: So you mean everything is ok?

Comment: No, just that #1 is not something to worry about.

Comment: Ok thanks, and what about Eclipse? Can i see it in my control panel or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below methods, goto tools->options
 1. Tick FOrce https:// to be http://
 2. Using proxy

Comment: Thanks, but it still remains in the **Done loading packages**
Is it finishes or not?
What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Sdk should get install, check your SDK location. SDK location is one that you set it, in Android Preference. You will find all the folders and document that you downloaded..

Answer (score 0):

Use a bundle with everything what you need from d.android.com
http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219.zip or sdk offline bundle:
http://qdevarena.blogspot.com/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html or here:
http://siddharthbarman.com/sidstream/index.php?r=software/apd

Comment: Can i ask your point of view about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882062/java-lang-runtimeexception-application-org-eclipse-ui-ide-workbench-could-not?

Comment: As I write there maybe eclipse -clean and reinstallation of adt should help, first delete plugin adt from Help->Install->What is already Installed?

Comment: The 3rd link is almost what i am looking for, but the "tutorial" in the page is not working (in the part "step-by-step tutorial") and about the "Second link" i do not know how to work with the package that i downloaded

Comment: The second link unpack package and run C:\eclipse\eclipse