# java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation

i am using Eclipse v21.10.1-569685 and JDK version 1.7.0_13-b20
When i downloaded new updates (Help-> Install New Software) after that Eclipse asked me to restart the software, but i faced with this error:

```
!SESSION 2013-04-10 06:49:45.348 -----------------------------------------------
        eclipse.buildId=v21.1.0-569685
        java.version=1.7.0_13
        java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
        BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
        Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
        Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

        !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-04-10 06:49:47.671
        !MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-04-10 06:49:47.671
        !MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt_0.10.1.v20120827-151636.jar was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt 2 0 2013-04-10 06:49:47.672
        !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench_0.9.1.
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-04-10 06:49:47.672
        .
        .
        .
        .

        !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-04-10 06:49:47.941
        !MESSAGE Application error
        !STACK 1
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher, org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate, org.eclipse.update.core.siteOptimizer, org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core.application, org.eclipse.cdt.core.GeneratePDOM, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool, org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaIndexer.
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
            at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
            at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
            at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
            at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

What should i do to run the Eclipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK thanks everyone I found the solution, which was the following:

1. Control Panel → View advanced system settings → Advanced tab → Environment Variables
2. Now you have to do 2 things:

   1. Create a new variable (click the New button):

      - Variable name: `JAVA_HOME`
      - Variable value: `C:\Program Files\Java\[your Java Version]`
   2. Edit the Path variable and add this to the end of that:

      ```
      ;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
      ```

Comment: Good! If you install MinGW and MinSYS, you have to add their bin paths to the Path variable, so now I understand your problem.

Comment: Having the same problem, you edited the Path variable... where?

Answer (score 4):

DELETE (or just move to a temporary folder) your $home/.eclipse folder (i.e., the config folder).

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" application is included in the org.eclipse.platform plugin. This plugin isn't include in your instance because some reason. Maybe, installing ADT invalid it.
Try to restore old configuration (Help>About>Installation details>Installation History) and reinstall ADT again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe eclipse -clean will help? First delete plugin adt from Help->Install->What is already Installed, second install adt from Market place, use Eclipse for Java or C++ developers (this with the Java schema).